# Is there a way to disable a blockchain validation?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I installed Bitcoin Full Node on Raspberry pi 3b+. Blockchain sync is dead slow because of less CPU. I Guess blockchain validation is time/CPU consuming thing. Is there a way to disable the validation and just download the chain? I understand the consequences. If my peers send wrong data, I will end up using wrong data. But I don't have an alternative. RPC calls are dead slow right now. I just need data to write some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It you just want to test your code with the Bitcoin Core RPC calls, you can use regtest mode by starting Bitcoin Core with `-regtest`. This mode sets up a private testing network so there is no need to sync the blockchain or connect to other peers unless you set up other peers to connect to. You can mine your own blocks in this mode too so blocks are produced when you want them.

Comment: on using command `bitcoind -regtest -daemon` i got `Error: Cannot obtain a lock on data directory /home/pi/.bitcoin/regtest. Bitcoin Core is probably already running.`. But when i typed `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`, i got `error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/pi/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

Comment: i was able to start correctly only with `bitcoind -daemon`

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no option to disable the block validation.

What you might want to do is a testnet sync. The download and the validation should finish much quicker. Depending on your use case the testnet chain should have similar data. However you won't find mainnet transactions or blocks.

You can enable testnet by starting Bitcoin Core with the `-testnet` option or creating a [bitcoin.conf](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) with `testnet=1`.

Comment: Someone could disable it in source code and recompile it.